# APC user cache entries not expiring

Tags: php, apc, ttl

I see 5 output each time when I run this code:

```
<?php
$v = 5;
apc_store('vwxyz',$v,3);
$before = apc_fetch('vwxyz');
sleep(5);
$after = apc_fetch('vwxyz'); //should be false
echo $before;
echo "<br>";
echo $after;
$later = apc_fetch('vwxyz'); //OK this should definitely be false
echo "<br>";
echo $later;
```

Shouldn't the cached entry be cleared from the cache and return false to apc_fetch()? The user_ttl setting is 2 for APC. I'm still trying to figure out what user_ttl does (the documentation is quite cryptic).

Answer (score 5):

From the [manual](http://php.net/apc_store):

> **Time To Live**; store ***var*** in the cache for ***ttl*** seconds. After the ***ttl***
>   has passed, the stored variable will be expunged from the cache (on
>   **the next request**). If no ***ttl*** is supplied (or if the ***ttl*** is 0), the
>   value will persist until it is removed from the cache manually, or
>   otherwise fails to exist in the cache (clear, restart, etc.).

So it says that the item gets removed from the cache *after* the TTL *on the next request*.  So the item isn't removed from cache until your next request which is why you keep getting 5.

Comment: Thanks drew. What does next request mean? Doesn't $later = apc_fetch('vwxyz'); count as the next request?

Comment: @tinkerr Next page request I'd assume, meaning a reload of the page.

Comment: @tinkerr Yeah by next request I believe they mean the next page request to PHP.  You can test this by fetching a value, print the result, store something to that key and let the request end.  Wait 1 second and refresh the page (it should still be set).  Then wait 5+ seconds, refresh the page (value should be gone).

Comment: Came across this issue also, read manual to mean "apc request" not "page request" which makes my unit test invalid. Ugh.

Comment: Same, my unit test failed and I couldn't figure out why. It sucks that I can't test ttl using a unit test.

Comment: I just ran further tests and all cache is cleaned up and maintained AFTER a read or write operation.

So if you write to cache with a ttl of 1, wait 2 seconds, then read from the same cache key, then it will still exist, then be erased after reading.
If you write with a ttl of 1, wait 2 seconds, then read from a different cache key, then attempt to read from the ttl 1 key, it will have been erased.

Essentially the cache cleans up TTL expired keys after any cache call.

These kinds of complications are why I don't worry about performance till bottlenecks show up.